# What happened to Ubuntu Certified Professional?

Tags: canonical

I would like to study and get some sort of qualification behind my name. I see there is a Linux Professional Institute exam - but what happened to the Ubuntu version?

How do I prove my knowledge of specifically Ubuntu at a job interview for example?

Comment: One way you can show your skills is to be a high ranked member of an Ubuntu community/forum.